# Ambiguity with circuit symbols

Tags: symbol

If I wanted to draw say a verical thermistor in a circuit diagram, it can look like any one of these four:

[image]

Is there a convention for which one to pick, or are all of them valid in any situation where a vertical thermistor is drawn?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here in a few days, you may want to try [electronics.se]

Comment: If someone suddenly asked me what that symbol meant, I would guess that that's a [photoresistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) rather than a thermistor.

Answer (score 2):

None of those look like a thermistor symbol to me. The usual schematic symbol looks like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Depending on whether the origin of the schematic is US/Asia or Europe respectively.

Edit:

Since it's an LDR- no the direction the light is coming from does not normally make a difference to the understandability of the schematic. It's a schematic, not a pictorial diagram. However, in the case where there is a light source closely coupled to the LDR which is part of the same schematic, it's common to show them together as below:

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-n6zFBtshAEQ/TaTpT1kuJ_I/AAAAAAAAAW4/V91kFNkF-AU/s1600/smoke-detector-circuit.gif]

The symbol shown in the above schematic is the one most commonly used in North America and Asia. The European symbol appears to be more like yours.

Comment: Thanks, I got the name mixed up with an LDR. But I would ask the same question: Is there a convention or do you just draw it anyway you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw any circuit symbol in any rotation or mirroring, but IME each symbol has a more-or-less standard orientation, that mostly coincides with 'information flows from left to right" and "current flows from top to bottom".

In the case of an LDR (that is waht you seem to mean) the light is first so the most common convention (again, IME) is to have the arrows at the left side (your top two symbols).

Of these two, the left one looks more familiar to me (maybe because light is supposed to come from above?).

But again, it is not strictly wrong to use any of the other orientations (or to rotate them 90 degrees).

And IME I see LDRs more often without the circle/ellips around the resistor rectangle.

Comment: If you make them horizontal, light is coming from above.

Answer (score 0):

You have a light dependent resistor.  Resistance changes as light changes.

[image]

There is no ambiguity in your symbols.  It just the rotation/mirroring of the symbol via different schematic packages.  It is common.